# Electrical dimmer switches for 4 switch locations?

Tags: dimmer-switch

I have a bank of 6 - LED 18watt (dimmable) bulbs and this bank has 4 switch locations.  Is it possible to dim this bank?  I don't see any 5 way dimmer switches offered.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

**There's more than one option!**

As ThreePhaseEel points out, Multi-location dimming is one option.

However, depending on usage, specifically the case where the lights will mostly always dimmed at the same level or just having the dimming capability at one location with the existing switch still in operation at the other 3 locations. That is, you'll replace one of the existing *3-way locations*, leaving remaining switches untouched.

If this is the case look for just ONE 3-way **PRESET dimmer**.

One example: Lutron LED compatible PRESET dimmer: http://a.co/aIBfTR0

(Ariadni, Toggler, Diva are all examples of preset in Lutron's product line) (Disclaimer, I don't work for Lutron. I do spec a lot of Lutron product for customers in my day job, as such I know the product lines--my only bonus for selling Lutron is the Lutron rep does take me to lunch 4 times a year.)

If dimmed the same all the time, this solution will be far less pricey than Multi-location, not to mention easier installation.

The only con is that one of the existing 3way locations (not a 4-way) must be picked for the replacement dimmer. If you open up the existing and find the switch has 4 screw terminals, just stop and put it back together and move on to another location.  If the switch you take apart has 3 terminals then the PRESET dimmer can be installed in that location.

Here is a wiring diagram for a 4 location switching. In the diagram, the center two switches are the 4-way switches, the outer two switches are 3-way switches.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### There are no 5-way dimmers because there are no 5-way switches

If you want to switch a light from 4 locations, you don't use a 5-way switch -- you need two 3-ways and two 4-ways instead.  Likewise, a *multi-location* dimming setup (that's the term you need) will be installed with a single master dimmer and matching remotes at all the other locations.

Comment: Thank you for the quick reply!  I did see the multi-location dimming setup and will go that way.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

There are options for supporting multiple switch locations for a set of lights where you can have dimming capability at each switch location. One option is to use a technology such as the Lutron Caseta smart switch with dimming capability. You install this switch in the location of one of the 3-way switches. Then the travellers are all tied together at the other switch locations so that the lights operate from the Caseta switch. At the remaining switch locations you install the Lutron Pico remote control RF device in a wall mount plate over the switch box. Multiple remotes can be used for 3, 4 or more control locations, each with switching and dimming capabilities. The remotes connect to the master switch via an RF wireless communication similar to the way a remote control garage door opener works.

<sup><sub>*(Note I have no interest in Lutron Caseta devices other than being a happy user).*</sub></sup>